# JanusGraph 1.0: Unable to delete nodes

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have JanusGraph 1.0 which has Cassandra as backend server. When trying to drop node using Gremlin console its properties gets removed but the node doesn't get dropped. Also tried dropping using vertex id, still it doesn't get dropped.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('Type','temp').valueMap(true)
==>{id=656949360, label=vertex}
==>{id=697888920, label=vertex}
==>{id=697893016, label=vertex}
```

If I search with g.V(656949360) it does not return any result but the above query returns result without any properties.
`
Note: Also verified server logs for JanusGraph and Cassandra but didn't find any error

Expected Result: Node should get removed and should not return for query g.V().has('Type','temp').drop()

Comment: Try using `g.V(656949360L)` - if you are connecting directly to the graph and not via a Gremlin Server, are you committing the transaction after deleting ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an index staleness issue. See if https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/advanced-topics/stale-index/ helps.